# How to show standardising the Normal Distribution from the p.d.f. using transformation?

Tags: normal-distribution

I know the approach from E[X] and Var[X] ect...

But is there a way to show z=(x-mu)/sigma gives the pdf of N(0,1^2)?

Something like

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (x-\mu)^2 \right\} $$

$$ Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} $$
So
$$ X = Z \sigma + \mu $$

$$ f\left( \sigma z + \mu \right) 
= 
\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} z^2 \right\}
$$

What I really want to get is
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2\pi}} exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2} z^2 \right\}
$$

How would I show it purely from the p.d.f using the transformation??

Comment: You get the extra factor of $\sigma$ from the "du" in the change of variables. Or equivalently you get it from the chain rule when you differentiate $F_Z \left ( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right )$.

Comment: Yep, but this really is a Linear transformation.... where does the Chain rule sort of come in ??? I find it a bit difficult to explain to the year 12....just from the point of view of a FUNCTION.

Comment: You can't fully explain it with just functions. You can sort of intuitively explain it by thinking about rectangles; if you make a rectangle $\sigma$ times wider then you need to make it $\sigma$ times shorter to keep the area the same. But to actually prove the formula you need calculus. The short route is to note that $F_X(x)=F_Z \left ( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right )$ and then differentiate to get $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma} f_Z \left ( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right )$.

Comment: @Ian Hmmmmm, I will see how I can explain this better only with graph transformations......avoid functions then.